# How sls_debug=* cmd works

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I wanted to know how deploying serverless project in debug mode works?

I generally use `sls deploy --satge dev` command to deploy my nodejs projects on aws. But somehow it is failing and I read on internet that I can use debug mode to get the logs.
So, now I'm using `sls_debug=* sls deploy --satge dev`. But I don't know where to see the logs so that I can pin point the failure.